# Is it possible to play multiple inline videos

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

This is my code with 2 videos. Code is very simple. On web browsers it works fine. I wanted it to play inline so I just added "playsinline".

Is is possible to play those 2 videos simultaneously?

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay controls playsinline loop muted id="a">
  <source src="https://hay.github.io/test/dog.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay controls playsinline loop muted id="b">
  <source src="https://hay.github.io/test/dog.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7nw5gLmk/

Comment: so you want to play video inline on ios device ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about playing html5 videos inline in iOS device then

**config.xml**

```
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
```

**HTML**

```
 <video src="https://hay.github.io/test/dog.mp4" width="200" preload="true" style="background:black" webkit-playsinline playsinline/>  
 <video src="https://hay.github.io/test/dog.mp4" width="200" preload="true" style="background:black" webkit-playsinline playsinline/>
```

**Note :- This works and tested for ios9 and ios10.**

Comment: Yep it worked for me. The problem was that I was using Ionic View app to test my iOS app but actually I had to build native iOS in order to work

Comment: you can select the answer as accepted if it helped, so it might be helpful to others. :)

Comment: Thanks @Anuj.T Your solution came to the rescue after hours of searching to make a third party lib to work in my cordova app.